# Is there a way to get hidden cell values from WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am iterating over the cells of my datagrid for purpose of generating a table (using iTextSharp for PDF generation) I wanted the table in my generated PDF to match what the user sees in the application (so in terms of sorting and column order etc).

```
            for (int i = 0; i < grid_caseTypes.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grid_caseTypes.Columns.Count; j++) {

                    var test = grid_caseTypes.Columns[j].GetCellContent(grid_caseTypes.Items[i] ) as TextBlock;

                    if (test!=null)
                    table.AddCell(test.Text);
                }
            }
```

where 'table' is an iTextSharp pdf table.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(grid_caseTypes.Columns.Count);
```

and grid_caseTypes is my data grid control

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid_caseTypes">
```

However when it gets to a row which is hidden (not visible on screen (beyond the boundaries of the XAML datagrid control) my cells are null. Even though the count of items in the data grid is 40 (I am only able to retrieve 12 rows worth of data)

**EDIT** - I know I have access to the ItemSource instead of the Items, however ItemSource gives the individual class objects which were used to fill in the cell values, and they have no sort order, data layout outside of the datagrid.  So I would lose any columns sorting ore reordering done on the datagrid.  Furthermore it involves me to check if the value I want is actually being used by the datagrid (if it was bound to the UI at all)  before adding it to my PDF table

Comment: In a well implememted MVVM scenario, your DataGrid will be fetched with data from the ViewModel, the latter being rendered on screen as deinided in the columns' data templates. Now, you are dealing with the virtualization of the DataGrid. There is a workaround to force the creation of the non-visible controls using the ItemsContainerGenerator, but that's not the proper way to go, i.e. you will lose the virtualization if you do so.

Comment: You're seeing the effects of virtualization. You could try turning off virtualization for the DataGrid by setting EnableRowVirtualization="False". I haven't tried that -- shadow32's method may work better.

Comment: @shadow32  I only need it for a moment - to generate the pdf, can 'ItemsContainerGenerator' (or EnableVirtualization set to false) be used  momentarily without affecting my current implementation?

Comment: If EnableVirtualization = false does not work for you, then it won't be momentary. Search for "force WPF to create item container" to start from somewhere.

Comment: @shadow32 Ok thanks, actually setting EnableRowVirtualization = false on my datagrid worked well ,all my rows are showing up in the pdf now.